# Chrome Postman Extension No Longer Available?

Tags: postman

I've been using the Chrome Postman Extension for quite some time now to test APIs.  I have also downloaded the standalone Postman Chrome App on my PC.  When I tried to access the extension through a saved URL on my browser this morning, I noticed that it no longer worked.  Also, I no longer see the extension version of Postman when searching within the Chrome store.

I personally prefer using the extension over the downloaded app.  Did the Postman Chrome extension get deprecated in favor of the stand alone app?

Comment: It may have.  I use the standalone app and that went to version 3.0 on me today (from 2.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A postman employee here. The browser based version of the app(legacy app) is pretty behind the latest app-v3.0. Due to some chrome platform limitations we are not able to add new features to the legacy app. So the legacy app will be eventually deprecated. Right now we have just delisted it from the chrome store as it is behind our latest app by a large measure. If you have an existing installation, it should continue working.

We would recommend v3.0, but if you still want to use the legacy app, can you drop us a mail at help@getpostman.com?