# Postman extension Chrome depricated retrieve history requests

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, postman

As mentiond Postman Chrome extension is not avialable: [Chrome Postman Extension No Longer Available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123405/chrome-postman-extension-no-longer-available)
For me it was still possible to start the application, until today the application can no longer be started, it's fully depricated.

I would like to see/transfer my history and favorites saved requests, how can I do that?

Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop/related

I tried to look through filexplorer inside
`C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage`
and
`C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\UserData\Default\Extensions\fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop\5.5.6_0`
but it is unclear.

It would be nice to open the program and copy manually the needed parts.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally solved it and retrieved all my saved API requests back by following these steps and javascript snippet:

1. Go to [chrome://extensions/](https://chrome://extensions/)
2. Scroll down to postman and click "background page".
3. Make sure to check first in Application tab, under "storage", go to IndexedDB -> Postman -> collection_requests.
4. In order to download this as JSON, go back to "Console" tab and enter:

```
const dbRequest = indexedDB.open('postman', 1);
dbRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
  const db = event.target.result;
  const transaction = db.transaction(['collection_requests'], 'readonly');
  const objectStore = transaction.objectStore('collection_requests');
  const allRecordsRequest = objectStore.getAll();
  allRecordsRequest.onsuccess = function() {
    const data = allRecordsRequest.result;
    const dataBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)], {type: 'application/json'});
    const dataUrl = URL.createObjectURL(dataBlob);
    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.href = dataUrl;
    downloadLink.download = 'postman_data.json';
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
  };
};
```

This will download a file with all saved requests if you want to retrieve historic requests I think they are in "requests".